# Make an Internal Static Method visible by another assembly

Tags: c#, methods, static, .net-assembly, internal

I cant find any solution to my problem which is :

```
 public static class1
{
    private static void Method()
    {
       //Implementation
```

I want to access the method in another assembly, i tried to put

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssembly2")] 

public static class1
    {
        internal static void Method()
        {
           //Implementation
```

But i can't see my method in MyAssembly2.

I don't want to make my method public or dynamic.
any ideas on how to do this??

Thanks

Theo

Comment: You want to access the Static Method from Second Assembly.?

Comment: Maybe this is a design issue? Can't you put all your classes in a single assembly?

Comment: Is any of your assemblies signed?

Comment: You can able to call Static .. you have to use REFLECTION to load the DLL and Access the Class and Static Method

Comment: But it begs the question, if you are treating this method like it is public, why not just make it public?

Comment: It should work. Mostly this construction is useful only for unit testing. Are you sure MyAssembly2 is really named MyAssembly2 and isn't signed ?

Comment: MyAssembly2 is not the real name : Balea.Wod.Business but my assemblies are not signed..

I dont want to make it public because the dll will be used by customers.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN's documentation on Friend Assemblie:

> When compiling an assembly (assembly B) that will access internal types or internal members of another assembly (assembly A), you must explicitly specify the name of the output file (.exe or .dll) with the /out compiler option (see /out for more information). This is required because the compiler has not yet generated the name for the assembly it is building at the time it is binding to external references.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0tke9fxk(en-us,vs.80).aspx

Check your compiler options and Rebuild both Assemblies.